# Set column to 0 with probability p

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I've got a matrix **A** with the dimensions m X n. For every column **i** (`i > 0`and `i <= n`) I want to flip a coin and fill the whole column with 0 values with probability p. How can this be accomplished in MATLAB?

Example:

A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8] and p = 0.5 could result in
A' = [1 0 3 0; 5 0 7 0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function rand() to generate an array of uniformly distributed random numbers, and use logical indexing to select colums where that array is less than p:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
p = 0.5;

A(:, rand(size(A,2), 1)<p) = 0

A =

     0     2     0     0
     0     6     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `bsxfun(@times, A, rand(1, size(A, 2)) > p)`. Alex's answer is admittedly better, though.